# Embed VLC into webpage without controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flash, video

I would like to embed a flash video into a webpage, but the trick is I don't want any of the controls to be visible.

I've already used VLC to successfully embed a flash video into the web page using:

```
<embed src="img/Wildlife.wmv" height="480" width="640">
```

But I don't want the viewer to be able to start or stop the video. They should just see the video playing and have no control at all.

Any ideas? I'm open to using something other than VLC if I must, as long as it plays .flv video.

Thanks!

Comment: Flash plays `.flv` just fine, and you will have better compatibility.  Why not just use it?  You realize that anything can use your embed tag... not just VLC.  You don't have any control over that player.

Comment: Oh, gotcha. Is there a way to specify no controls or something in the embed option then, assuming i set my default player to flash?

Comment: What I suggest you do is build a (or use one of the existing) Flash Movie that plays your `.flv`.  Then, you have all the options you want for hiding controls.  http://www.longtailvideo.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use vlc, see http://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation%3aWebPlugin.
You can try setting autoplay = true, loop = true, controls = false, that will possibly do the trick; but if you need to play only flv you'd better follow Brad's advice.